# Reordering match clauses in a recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, optimization, ocaml

I have some Ocaml courses at school, and for an exercise we must write the function length.

My teacher showed us how Xavier Leroy wrote his function :

```
let rec length_aux len = function
   [] -> len
 | a::l -> length_aux (len + 1) l

let length l = length_aux 0 l
```

When my teacher explained us why he do the length function like that, he said he didn't know why Xavier Leroy didn't write:

```
let rec length_aux len = function
   a::l -> length_aux (len + 1) l
 | [] -> len

let length l = length_aux 0 l
```

... in order to make it faster (since most of the cases the list in nonempty).

So if someone knows why the second one is no better than the first one, could you answer me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "in order to make this better"? The two versions are identical.

Comment: I think it's good practice to put the base case first, since if your patterns aren't disjoint it'll match them in order, and you usually want the base case to "override" other patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OCaml, this is the same function. The pattern matching will be compiled to a test on whether the list is empty or not, and jump to a side or the other.

Similar code in C would be reordering cases in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Okey so if I understand, in Ocaml the patern matching will do the two test almost in the same time ?

Comment: it's not so much "at the same time" as just "optimized". Because pattern matching is more restrictive and "richer" than imperative if-else branches, and in particular because simple patterns can't have side-effects so order of execution does not matter, it can be analyzed and optimized quite heavily.